# How to call ldrLoadDll on another thread of another app?

Tags: c++, winapi

I did the simplest injector NtCreateThreadEx + LdrLoadDll, but the injector injects dll into itself and not into the target process (using `LoadLibraryW` instead of `LdrLoadDll ((wchar_t *) 0, 0, & name, & Module))`, it works correctly - how can I fix the problem in the simplest way

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

using namespace std;

EXTERN_C NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtCreateThreadEx(PHANDLE,
    ACCESS_MASK, LPVOID, HANDLE, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, LPVOID,
    BOOL, SIZE_T, SIZE_T, SIZE_T, LPVOID);

typedef HMODULE(__stdcall* _LdrLoadDll)(
    wchar_t* PathToFile,
    unsigned long Flags,
    PUNICODE_STRING ModuleFileName,
    PHANDLE* ModuleHandle
    );
_LdrLoadDll LdrLoadDll;

int main()
{
    DWORD targetProcId = 10340; //Proc id to inject
    wchar_t targetDllPath[255] = L"C:\\DllTest32.dll"; //dll path to inject


    unsigned short targetDllPathLength = sizeof(targetDllPath);
    HANDLE targetOpened = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, targetProcId);
    LPVOID allocatedMem = VirtualAllocEx(targetOpened, 0, targetDllPathLength, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    bool wpm = WriteProcessMemory(targetOpened, allocatedMem, targetDllPath, targetDllPathLength, 0);

    LdrLoadDll = (_LdrLoadDll)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "LdrLoadDll");
    UNICODE_STRING name;
    name.Buffer = targetDllPath;
    name.Length = wcslen(name.Buffer) * sizeof(wchar_t);
    name.MaximumLength = name.Length + sizeof(wchar_t);
    PHANDLE Module;


    HANDLE rt;
    NtCreateThreadEx(
        &rt, PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, NULL, targetOpened,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LdrLoadDll((wchar_t*)0, 0, &name, &Module),
        allocatedMem, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: inject shell code and call `LdrLoadDll` from it.

Comment: Can I call it without asm?

Comment: can, but need deep knowledge

Comment: You are *calling* `LdrLoadDll()` within the injecting process, not the target process, and then you are passing its *return value* to `NtCreateThreadEx()`. That is not how remote injection works. You would need to marshal the input parameters for `LdrLoadDll()` into the other process first, then pass the *address* of `LdrLoadDll()` to `NtCreateThreadEx()`, that way `LdrLoadDll()` can use the parameters when the remote thread calls it. However, the signature of `LdrLoadDll()` is not compatible with `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`, but `LoadLibrary(A|W)()` is, so why aren't you using that instead?

Comment: Thanks, I just want to learn other injection methods besides loadLibrary and understand how it works in depth)

May I ask for an example not necessarily ldrLoadDll, just any function that takes a parameter from another thread and is executed on that remote thread

Comment: @Gorilka there are many examples on StackOverflow demonstrating remote injection via `CreateRemoteThread()` and `LoadLibrary()`